# Сортировка массивов php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, сортировка

Стала задача отсортировать массив, приходящий из БД. Один элелемент из этого массива выглядит так:

```
Array ( [id] => 261 [category] => 1 [subcategory] => 83 [name] => Гель-краска 10 г цвет 02 [name_tr] => [description] =>[description_tr] =>[price-usd] => [price-usd-promo] => [price-try] => [price-try-promo] => [price-rub] => [price-rub-promo] => [image] => 02в.jpg [sku] => [status] => 1 [novelty] => [recommended] => [promo] => [sales] => [hits] => [type] => 2 [volume] => [width] => [height] => [thickness] => [weight] => [material] => [abrasiveness] => [seo_title] => [seo_description] => [seo_keywords] => )
```

Надо отсортировать этот массив по полю ***name*** по возрастанию. Имена для одной категории не меняются, но меняются для иной. В конце обязательно стоит число вида

> 01,
>   02,
>   021

Можно выполнить сортировку при SQL-запросе

`$sql ="SELECT * FROM c_products WHERE category = '".$category[0]['id']."' AND status = '1' AND subcategory = '".$subcategory[0]['id']."' ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT $offset,$num ";`

При существующей сортировке выводится следующим образом

> 01, 011, 012, 02, 020

Comment: Так вам нужно отсортировать именно по этому последнему числу в name не учитывая всё остальное?

Comment: Да, при том, что имена меняются, а длина числа может состоять из 2-х или 3-х цифр.

Comment: самое правильное - хранить эти данные в БД в отдельной колонке. Как и граммы. И все танцы с бубном уйдут. То, что у вас сейчас - это не имя. Это имя и характеристики товара (вес и цвет). Они должны быть отдельно.

Comment: Полностью согласен, но сайт дали на доработку и товары уже залиты, поэтому переделывать пока более трудозатратно, чем допилить сортировку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для сортировки данных в php можно воспользоваться функцией [usort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php)

```
$data = [
  ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Name qweqweqwe 17'],
  ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'Name qweqweqwe 09'],
  ['id' => 4, 'name' => 'Name qweqweqwe 2'],
  ['id' => 5, 'name' => 'Name qweqweqwe 15'],
  ['id' => 7, 'name' => 'Name qweqweqwe 021'],
  ['id' => 9, 'name' => 'Name qweqweqwe 8'],
];

usort($data, function($a, $b){
  $a = explode(' ', $a['name']);
  $b = explode(' ', $b['name']);
  return array_pop($a) - array_pop($b);
});

print_r($data);
```

[3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/#preview)

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю так: заводите массив в который будете помещать все полученные из БД данные и массив для кода цвета. Все полученные данные перебираете и name режете на куски. Т.к. в конце всегда стоит нужный нам для сортировки номер, то получаем его и заносим во второй массив для кода цвета, а все данные в первый массив. Далее уже сортируем наш новый массив с помощью другого массива и работаем с ним. Примерно вот так (тут просто для одного name):

```
$global_array=[]; //Глобальный массив в который помщаем все данных из запроса и цвет отдельной переменной
$sorting_values=[]; //значния для сортировки - код цвета

$name='Гель-краска 10 г цвет 02';
$name_arr=explode(' ', $name); //режем name на части по пробелу
$сolor=array_pop($name_arr); //получаем последнюю часть массива с кусками name, т.е. код цвета
$global_array[]=$name; //заносим нужные данные в глобальный массив (все переменные из запроса). НО ключи - цифры по порядку! Вам тут скорее всего нужно будет завести многомерный массив
$sorting_values[]=$сolor; //код цвета в отдельный массив. Ключи тоже цифры по порядку. Они должны совпадать с указанными в $global_array


array_multisort($sorting_values, $global_array); //сортируем массив global_array по sorting_values
print_r($global_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Структуру данных нужно менять. Предложу план безболезненного перехода.

#### Миграция данных

- Заведите новые колонки для значимых данных (`title`, `weight`, `color`)
- Напишите скрипт, который разбирает `name` и заполняет новые поля.

#### Поддержание консистенции

Для поддержания консистенции данных во время эксплуатации нужно изменить весь код, работающий с этими данными.

Поэтому на это время предлагаю добавить в базу триггер, разбирающий `name` на части при вставке или обновлении.
Во многих фреймворках также можно поместить вызов ранее написанной функции в хуки ORM.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду пробовать